# How to keep number format that I use in excel intact while saving the same in CSV format?

Tags: excel

When I save an excel sheet into CSV, usually a pop up display appears stating that some features may lost while saving in CSV format. I want to overcome this.
E.g:
Cell A1 has 020
Cell A2 has 020
Cell A3 has 020

If I save this in CSV format, the leading is removed. I want to keep the leading zeroes as it is in csv format. Please help

Comment: Have you checked the inside of the CSV after the save, by opening it in a text editor like Notepad? Excel fumbles with the data in a CSV when it opens it.

Comment: It works fine, if the CSV is opened in a text editor. But the same does not work fine if I open it in an excel. Kindly help

Comment: Don't **OPEN** the file in Excel.  Rather **IMPORT** the file, using either the legacy wizard or Power Query, and designate that column as "Text".